# Rendering unity multiple scenes from android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, integration

I have a issue with unity and android integration i wanna make when user click a button in android app then unity scene should render like wise if there are any multiple scenes when user click the button each unity scene should render

I already added unity as a library to android app and one when user click button only one scene rendering

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example of what the code might look like...

In your Unity C# script (let's call it SceneController):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }
}
```

In your Android app's code (Java/Kotlin):

```
// Assuming you have a button click listener
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Call the Unity method to load and render scenes
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UnityGameObjectName", "LoadScene", "SceneName");
    }
});
```

In this example, replace "UnityGameObjectName" with the actual name of the GameObject in your Unity scene that has the SceneController script attached, and "SceneName" with the name of the scene you want to load and render.

Comment: any AI involved in the writing of this answer?

Comment: No, I wrote it myself